# SimpleDateFormat in non-lenient modus throws ParseException while parsing a valid date

Tags: java, parsing, scala, simpledateformat

I have a very simple scala class:

```
class StrictDateFormat(pattern: String) extends java.text.SimpleDateFormat {
  setLenient(false)
}
```

I am getting a ParseException while parsing a valid date:

```
new StrictDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse("2013-02-05 16:47")
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-02-05 16:47"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

I have tried everything, it does not work.

Amazingly, if I set the lenient method while instantiating a SimpleDataFormat, it works:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"){setLenient(false)}.parse("2013-02-05 16:47")
res0: java.util.Date = Tue Feb 05 16:47:00 CET 2013
```

This makes no sense!  Is not this the same class as the the one I had declared?
Why I am getting a ParseException in the first case?
Is this a bug in java or in scala?

My Java version: jdk1.6.0_26
My scala version: 2.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
class StrictDateFormat(pattern: String) extends java.text.SimpleDateFormat(pattern) {
  setLenient(false)
}
```

(Call the correct superclass constructor `java.text.SimpleDateFormat(pattern)` instead of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`)